# Question on the definition and usage of "fiber derivative"

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, definition, differential-topology

I'm going through Hirsch's "Differential Topology" and am trying to make my way through the proof of Theorem 5.3 on Page 112.

The theorem is Let $M \subset V$ be a sub manifold, $\delta M = \delta V = \emptyset$. Then any two tubular neighborhoods of $M$ in $V$ are isotopic.

Let $(f_i, \gamma_i)$ for $i=0,1$ be our tubuluar neighborhoods. We first prove the theorem under the assumption that $f_0(E_0) \subset f_1(E_1)$.

The text then reads:

"Let $\Phi: \gamma_0 \rightarrow \gamma_1$ be the fibre derivative of $g = f_1^{-1} f_0: E_0 \rightarrow E_1$. Thus $\Phi$ is the component along the fibres of the morphism:

$T_M g: T_M E_0 = TM \oplus \gamma_0 \rightarrow TM \oplus \gamma_1 = T_M E_1$

Which shows that $\Phi$ is an isomorphism of vector bundles.

What exaclty does it mean to say that "Thus $\Phi$ is the component along the fibres"? Can somebody reword this for me give me some insight, whether technical or intuitive.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hirsch defines what it is in that sentence. Here $E$ and $F$ are vector bundles over $M$ and you have a bundle map $\Phi\colon E\to F$ covering the identity map on $M$. If you restrict $d\Phi$ to the (tangent space to the) fiber $E_p$, this is the fiber derivative, mapping $E_p$ to $F_p$. Using a trivialization over $U\subset M$, you can write coordinates $(x,v)$ on $E|_U$ and $(x,w)$ on $F|_U$. (Fixing $x$ and varying $v$ over $\Bbb R^k$ represents the fiber of $E$ over $x$.) Then $\Phi$ looks like
$$g(x,v) = (x,h(x,v))$$
and the fiber derivative at $(x,v)$ on the tangent vector $(0,\xi)$ to the fiber is given by $dh_{(x,v)}(0,\xi)$.

Comment: The tangent space to the fiber $E_p$ and the fiber $E_p$ are isomorphic, right? Thanks for being patient by the way, I know i'm not the fastest learner, but I do love math!!

Comment: Yes, because the tangent space to a vector space at any element is naturally the vector space. :)

Comment: Interesting. So the restriction of $d \Phi$ to the vector spaces of elements in the image of the zero section of the bundle and $\Phi$ are both maps that take fibers to fibers, but they are indeed different maps that contain different information.. I'll think about it some more.

Comment: Wait. What do you mean by "elements in the image of the zero section"? How is $d\Phi$ taking those to the fiber? ... Are you thinking about the intrinsic derivative of a section at a zero?

Comment: Oh, right... The zero section maps elements of the base space to the zero vector in the total space that projects down to it. I meant the restriction of $d \Phi$ to the vector spaces that compose $TM$ in the direct product $T_M E = TM \oplus \gamma$ where $\gamma = (p,E,M)$

Comment: $T_M E$ is an interesting object to me... since $E$ is already a bunch of vector spaces parameterized by $M$, looking at the tangent space of $E$ in any way shape or form is sort of a tough concept for me, but I'm getting the hang of it I think.

By the way, what is the map $h$ in your answer?

Comment: What you wrote a comment earlier makes no sense to me. $T_ME = TM\oplus E$ is the Whitney sum of the two bundles on the zero section (which is a copy of $M$). $\gamma = (p,E,M)$???

Comment: $\gamma = (p,E,M)$ is a vector bundle, projection map $p$, total space $E$, base space $M$. I was following the notation of Hirsch in theorem 2.1 on page 94, how in this case $T_M E \cong \gamma \oplus TM$. I'm definitely mixing up some terminology and not expressing my thoughts clearly though... I've been trying to understand this stuff too long >.< going to go on a run haha thanks though your the best!

Comment: OK, you win ... :)